# C++ OpenCV - Creating a 3D matrix and access its elements

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to use a 3D matrix in OpenCV to store and access data (type float). Currently I have 3 methods to create the 3D matrix itself of size 158 x 98 x 32 and initialize it at zero:

```
int out[3];
out[0] = 98;
out[1] = 158;
out[2] = 32;

//Alternative 1:
cv::Mat M(3, out, CV_32FC1, cv::Scalar(0));

//Alternative 2:
cv::Mat M(3, out, CV_32F);
M = Scalar(0);

//Alternative 3:
Mat *feat = new Mat(3,out,CV_32F,Scalar(0));
Mat M = *feat;
```

Then I use the .data function to obtain a pointer to the first data element:

```
unsigned char *input = (unsigned char*)(M.data);
```

Next, I thought I could set the first element (0,0,0) to 1 by using either of the following two methods:

```
input[0]= 1;             //Alternative 1
M.at<float>(0,0,0) = 1;  //Alternative 2
```

The at() method works just fine, but I can't seem to get the pointer to work. The following:

```
input[0]= 1;
input[1]= 2;
```

Results in 4.32e-42 at element (0,0,0) while the other command seems to have no effect at all. According to the documentation, input[0] should refer to the value at point (0,0,0), input[1] to (0,0,1) and input[32] to (0,1,0) etc.

Also, the M.step is set to 0 and M.cols and M.rows are both -1. The number of rows and columns seems right for a multidimensional matrix, but the step should have a value, right?

So, which of the 3 alternatives is best to initialize the 3D matrix and how can I use pointers to access each data elements separately?

By the way, I'm using the following code to output the contents of the matrix (any other ideas are welcome as well):

```
float M_res = 0;
ofstream res;
res.open("Results.txt"); //Open file

for(int loopz=0;loopz<out[2];loopz++) {
  res << endl << endl << "Dimension " << loopz << endl;
    for(int loopy=0;loopy<out[0];loopy++) {
      res << endl;
      for(int loopx=0;loopx<out[1];loopx++) {
        M_res = M.at<float>(loopy,loopx,loopz)
        res << M_res << " ";
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any thoughts on this? All ideas are very welcome!

Comment: It seems like this line is erroneous:

    Then I use the .data function to obtain a pointer to the first data element:

    unsigned char *input = (unsigned char*)(M.data);

since the matrix M type is float therefore you should use

    float *input = (float *)(M.data);

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I write the answer to whomever comes and passes by.

Two separate questions: initializing matrices and accessing multidimensional array elements.

---

For the **first question**, on initializing matrices, I would state that all three are functional. However, the first is the best one since it is encapsulated in a standard cv constructor. The second one I would say that is exactly an homologue, since you are creating a matrix which is an object with a data object inside. Stating `M = Scalar(0)` is just initializing all values of the data object inside `M`, as in alternative 1. The third case is like the first, but through a pointer. To provide more clarity on the subject, I hope the next paragraph from [Learning OpenCV 3: Computer Vision in C++ with the OpenCV Library](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491937998):

> In addition, some of these [constructors] allow you to initialize the data, either by providing a cv::Scalar (in which case, the entire array will be initialized to that value), or by providing a pointer to an appropriate data block that can be used by the array. In this latter case, you are essentially just creating a header to the existing data (i.e., no data is copied; the data member is set to point to the data indicated by the data argument).

---

Regarding the **second question**, accessing elements. We are dealing with a single valued 3 dimensional matrix. To access the elements individually, there are different options: by location or iteration.

Location supports two standard ways: `at<>()` and `ptr<>()`. The second is slightly faster than the first. To put in a example, as you already put an example for the first:

`M.ptr<float>(3)` will access the address of the first element in row 3. With this and knowing if values are conitnuous in memory (with `isContinuous`), you can run through it by accessing the values, `*M.ptr<float>(i)`.

For example, while refactoring your code:

```
    int out[3] = {98, 158, 32};

    //Alternative 1:
    cv::Mat M(3, out, CV_32F, cv::Scalar(0));

    cout << "Total size " << M.size <<" and, for example, rows " << M.size[0] << endl;

    cout << "IS the matrix really continuous? " << M.isContinuous() << " Yes" << endl;
    int counter = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < M.size[0]; r++){
        float* p = M.ptr<float>(r);
        for (int c = 0; c < M.size[1]*M.size[2]; c++){
            *(p + c);
            counter += 1;
        }
    }
    cout << "Number of elements seen " << counter << " matrix number of elements " << 98*158*32 << endl;
```

Outputs:

```
Total size 98 x 158 x 32 and, for example, rows 98
IS the matrix really continuous? 1 Yes
Number of elements seen 495488 matrix number of elements 495488
```

The last way to access elements is by the use of iterators, which work as in STL.

```
    cv::MatConstIterator_<float> it = M.begin<float>();

    while ( it != M.end<float>()){
        *it;
    }
```

But accessing by pointer is faster.

Also, to access them in group you can check the same book, *chapter 4, Section Accessing Array Elements by Block*, or the OpenCV docs for methods of `m.row`, `m.col`, and others, where m is `cv::Mat`.