# How to creat a 3-d matrix using Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I want to use these code to create a 3-d matrix

```
int size[3] = { 100, 100,100};
cv::Mat mat3D(3, size, CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(0));
```

but after I debug my code, I find
[image]
it seems that I don't get the right matrix, what's the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ OpenCV - Creating a 3D matrix and access its elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30448976/c-opencv-creating-a-3d-matrix-and-access-its-elements)

Comment: Just write some test to verify if it works. It is more like limit of debuger plugin.

Comment: Is there a difference if you choose CV_8U instead of CV_8UC1?

Comment: there should not since CV_8U == CV_8UC1 (they literally have the same value)

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems ok, maybe the debugger is misinterpreting.

This code displays well the 24 elements (I changed the dimensions to have a smaller matrix)

```
 int size[3] = { 2, 3, 4};
cv::Mat mat3D(3, size, CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(0));
std::cout << "Total size " << mat3D.size << std::endl;
int counter = 0;
for(cv::MatConstIterator_<uchar> it = mat3D.begin<uchar>(); it != mat3D.end<uchar>(); ++it){
    std::cout << " " << (int) *it;
    counter ++;
}
std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << counter << " elts" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct.

Concerning your debugger output, when dealing with multidimensional cv::Mat it is the expected behaviour. [The OpenCV documentation for `cv:Mat::rows`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#abed816466c45234254d25bc59c31245e) reads: *"the number of rows and columns or (-1, -1) when the matrix has more than 2 dimensions"*. Indeed, your debugger displays the values of channels x rows x columns (1 x -1 x -1).

You can try this to enumerate some `cv::Mat` related attributes:

```cpp
    std::cout
        << "dims       : " << mat3D.rows
        << "\nchannels() : " << mat3D.channels()
        << "\nrows       : " << mat3D.rows
        << "\ncols       : " << mat3D.cols
        << "\nsize()     : " << mat3D.size()
        << "\nsize       : " << mat3D.size;
```

Your output should be:

```
dims       : 3
channels() : 1
rows       : -1
cols       : -1
size()     : [-1 x -1]
size       : 1000 x 100 x 100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
int DImensions3D[] = { 100,100 ,100 };
cv::Mat RTstruct3D(3,DImensions3D, CV_8U, Scalar(0));
```

Comment: Please could you make it clearer what you changed and why that solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

**One way is, you can use .reshape()**

*if you have one dimensional array*

*you can convert it to **3x3** array using below code*

```
int x[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int len_x = sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]);

cv::Mat mat3D(1,len_x, CV_32S,x);
mat3D = mat3D.reshape(3,3); //(dimension, height)
```